# Dunce hat with a vertex point removed is homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Define $T = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x,y\geq 0, x + y \leq 1 \}$ and let $(x,0) \sim (0,x)$ and $(x, 0) \sim (x, 1-x)$ be an equivalence relation on $T$. Then $D := T/ \sim $, is our **standard dunce hat**.

Show that $D \setminus \{[(0,0]\}$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^1$. Here $\vee$ is the wedge sum, and $S^1 \vee S^1$ looks like the figure "8".

How do I show this? In fact I'm not even sure *why* this is true. I can't make the deformation in my head (the dunce hat is hard to imagine to begin with. Not sure what it looks like with a point removed). I can guess that the meeting point in the two circles in $S^1 \vee S^1$ will be the identified with $[(1,0)]$ but that's about it.

Comment: I don’t get the “standard dunce hat” joke

Comment: I defined it above. I'm just remarking that my definition is essentially the same as the general construction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunce_hat_(topology)

Edit: sounds like you've just never heard of the object.

Comment: $[(0,1)]$ can’t be the meeting point because it is deleted too.

Comment: Try to draw a graph of your space. Because you've exclude the equiv classes of $(0,0)$, which means the vertices are removed, you can always expand the holes created by the removal of these points, which will help you get an intuition at least.